# files saved in NTFS partition are not accessible

Tags: 11.10, ntfs

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 in dual boot.
I took a screenshot in Ubuntu and saved it to the NTFS partition.
I can view the file from ubuntu but when i come to windows it doesnt opens the file.
When i check the file properties in windows it shows 0 byte.

How can i access the file?
Is there any way to fix the problem ?

Comment: Have you done a Windows/NTFS **chkdsk /f**, to check for corruption?  I am currently using (latest update of) **Ubuntu 11.10** (32bit) and **Windows 7** (32bit), and do **NOT** experience this issue.

Comment: Another way to cause this is to hibernate Windows, boot Ubuntu, and then write files to the NTFS partition...

Answer (score 1):

There is a "bug" with the new implementation of NFS on Windows. I do not know a solution, but will watch for one. You will need to look for a work around - either a FAT or EXT4 data partition (with the fs driver installed on windows). Similar bug repost - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/675290

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to set up samba and do a network share http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/04/share-files-folders-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/
or this should wk too http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=469666
this also has some useful info too :-)

Comment: the OP is talking about saving to the NTFS partition locally, not over a network share (samba or NFS).

Comment: the second link gives a nice solution to ntfs partion access :-)

Comment: Yes, but as I indicated that is not the problem. Also, it is preferable to answer the question - provide details, and reference the link rather then answering a question with links.

Comment: ah point taken :-)